# Power management : Configuring Battery cutoff voltage

Tags: battery

I've been looking so far without any result yet.

What and where are the configuration files editable to change anything about the power management, specifically, the cutoff voltage ?

Any hints will help. (Something in the ROM? in the kernel ? in some drivers ?)

Working on a rooted Android 4.3

Comment: Sorry, my answer is not relevant, hence deleted- you were asking for *config* files , I missed that and gave you actual file location

Comment: [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145263/131553) suggested it is kernel related

Comment: Huh, we need to know that device. What make and model?

Comment: I do believe it's a Ingenic based device. Probably the newton 2 thing, but actually, i'm not looking for an exact file location, but for hints about where to search them. Something generic enough for that anyone can relate to it' device and apply to search the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using Xposed Framework. You can actually turnoff auto-shutoff of any android device on 0% battery. by using [Disable critical battery shutdown](https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-the-critical-battery-shutdown-with-xposed-module/) and run your battery upto a voltage you want.
Notice : This will require root permission