# Show battery at 100% when it is charged to lower value?

Tags: root-access, battery, charging

On the Samsung Galaxy Tab S7, you can limit your battery to 85% and have it show 100% when it is at 85%.

Can I somehow replicate this behaviour on my OnePlus 6 running on LineageOS 18.1 with root?
I am already limiting charging to 85% through ACCA with a brand new battery, and would like the capacity at that point to be considered 100% to the phone as well.

Comment: What do you achieve by that? ACCA can disable charging and if your Kernel supports do idle charging also //I am missing the advantage of your approach. What do you gain?

Comment: I want to preserve my battery's health and have it display 85% as 100%. I dont want to contantly feel like I should squeeze out the remaining 15% and return to fully charging to the real 100% every night. If I can do it on my Tab S7, can I do it on my phone as well?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because the [battery capacity files are located in kernel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145263/where-are-the-battery-capacity-files-located) and it's not easy to tinker with kernel // But, wait for knowledgeable folks to comment or answer