# Is possible to charge the battery even If I erase boot and system partitions?

Tags: battery, charging, fastboot

Is it possible? Or the device needs at least a kernel to be able to charge? I have a device in bootloop that every 3 seconds it vibrates and I'm not sure if its does not charge because I erased boot and system partitions or because its consume power everytime it vibrates preventing to charge enough for me be able to turn on fastboot mode and fix it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. This may be relevant https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145263/where-are-the-battery-capacity-files-located?r=SearchResults&s=1|105.2026

Comment: In other words, the presence of battery, it's capacity, is current voltage levels etc are communicated by system and if that's missing, will it charge? I don't think it will

Comment: It's very hardware-specific question, so cannot be answered with surety. It depends on your OEM's choice of SoC/PMIC and bootloader (the components which load before the actual OS). But it's definitely possible. U-Boot is a commonly used open-source bootloader, and it does have a pretty thorough [support for battery charging](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.power-framework), without relying on Linux/Android kernel.

Comment: my device's current bootloader is lk(little kernel), I can boot in lk and choose the boot mode (normal, recovery or fastboot) but when I select anyone it shutdown, I tried let it charging while in lk but it just charge for less than 2 minutes and then shutdown, idk if lk have some kind of timeout of inactivity and shudown when its reach this timeout or its just do not support charge :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know what TWRP is, you should just install and boot into it and charge. However in your case you cant install it i guess. So best way is to plug into pc and fastboot mode the device. This will supply it with some power at least and try flashing twrp to it using adb/fastboot services. Then you can boot into twrp and charge the device from there. And if in future you're ever going to touch a phone's system/other important partitions..make sure to install twrp beforehand.